# Package for nonlinear plot coordinates

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts, ticks

**Is there a package for plotting in nonlinear coordinates?**

I mean that I provide coordinate transformation functions `{xi(x,y), eta(x,y)}`, for example `{1/x,Log[y]}`, and get plot in this coordinates with transformed grid and automatically set ticks to make 'em look equidistant

```
Solve[{xi(x,y)-xiIMinusOne==stepXi,eta(x,y)-etaIMinusOne==stepEta},{x,y}]
```

and **mitigating all M. bugs** in `Plot` function?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am interpreting your question correctly, but if you want to plot a function of the new coordinates, you can use ParametricPlot3D in this way
(I am here using a working example from a very old notebook - it refers to polar coordinates - you might have to invert your transformations)

```
f[x_, y_] := 3Exp[-x^2 - y^2]

ParametricPlot3D[{
        x = r Cos[θ],
        y = r Sin[θ],
        f[x, y]},
    {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, 2Pi},
    PlotRange -> All,   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5},    PlotPoints -> {10, 40}]
```

Otherwise, if you want to plot the transformed grid in the the new coordinate system, I believe you can find the solution to your problem in Xah Lee's [Transform2DPlot.m package](http://xahlee.info/MathGraphicsGallery_dir/Transform2DPlot_dir/transform2DPlot.html). This is the man's website http://xahlee.info/. This is the math part of if http://xahlee.info/math_software/mathPrograms.html. Sadly, it appears [he is not doing well](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/xah_as_good_as_dead.html) lately.

EDIT: I see now the package is no longer free to download but requires the payment of a fee.